# Action setprods on EOSIO v2.0 private chain

Tags: cleos

I'm standing up a new private testnet and would like to set the producers via the "setprods" action in the eosio.bios contract. I don't need a full system contract for this chain. The format for the command has changed due to WTMsig Block Production feature introduced in the new v2.0 software update. All documentation refers to the old command.

When I run:

```
cleos -u http://localnet.com:8888 push action eosio setprods {"schedule":[{"producer_name":"eosio","authority":[{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS8FLEDoQfhRFnnvUjDBF8wmjYfgkqZVJd1nJeAATtDfG6cp9wsn","weight":1}]}]}]}

    no matches found: {schedule:[producer_name:eosio]}
```

I've followed the contract ABI, however, I'm unable to set a new schedule. The same applies if I add my second BP to the command.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This documentation should have the latest steps on setup producer.

https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence/#2-transition-from-single-genesis-producer-to-multiple-producers

Setting up the eosio network requires multiple steps. Any step skipped could result in an error. Probably it is better to follow that guide step by step

Comment: Yes, you are correct, there is a reference to the "setprods" action in the eosio.bios contract documentation, however, there is no example of the "schedule". I'm deliberately not following the guide because I'm not interested in the full system contract for this testnet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the json that worked for me. Thanks to dfuse.io team for assistance.

command:

```
cleos -u http://localnetwork.com:8888 push action eosio setprods "testnetprods.json" -p eosio@active
```

testnetprods.json:

```
{
    "schedule": [
        {
            "producer_name": "eosio",
            "authority": [
                "block_signing_authority_v0",
                {
                    "threshold": 1,
                    "keys": [
                        {
                            "key": "EOS8xxxx",
                            "weight": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },{
            "producer_name": "bp2",
            "authority": [
                "block_signing_authority_v0",
                {
                    "threshold": 1,
                    "keys": [
                        {
                            "key": "EOSxxxxx",
                            "weight": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Updated Schedule

```
    active schedule version 1
        Producer      Producer Authority
        ============= ==================
        eosio         {"threshold":1,"keys [{"key":"EOSxxxx","weight":1}]}
        bp2           {"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOSxxxx","weight":1}]}

    pending schedule empty

    proposed schedule empty
```